# Android - Set padding to RadioButton pin

Tags: android, xml, padding, styling, android-radiobutton

I'have tried lot of combination both with xml and programmatically but nothing to do yet.
This is the scenario (pay attention to the small red arrow):

[image]

I have some RadioButtons inside a radio group, in xml this scenario could be represented as:

```
<RadioGroup
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/radiobuttons"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:dividerPadding="30dp">
   <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="How to set the padding on the left of radio pin"
      android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"/>
  <!-- other radio buttons... -->
</RadioGroup>
```

My problem is that I didn't find a way to set the left padding of the circle pin neither in xml nor programmatically (I'm interested in both).
In fact each padding that I tried to modify in a RadioButton object seems to refer only to the text inside of it (i.e. java functions setPadding and setCompoundDrawablePadding, or xml android:paddingLeft and android:drawablePadding don't work).

My container_dropshadow.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
   <item>
      <shape>
         <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
         <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
  </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape>
         <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
         <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape>
         <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
         <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape>
         <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
         <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
      <shape>
         <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
         <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
      </shape>
   </item>
   <!-- Background -->
   <item>
      <shape>
         <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
         <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 51):

I found a way, by using an inset drawable:

First, create a new inset drawable (e.g. radio_button_inset.xml) with your desired padding and a link to the theme radio button drawable like this:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:drawable="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
      android:insetLeft="@dimen/your_padding_value"/>
```

Second, use this new drawable for your radio button:

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="How to set the padding on the left of radio pin"
      android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
      android:button="@drawable/radio_button_inset"/>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome logic. Worked!

Comment: how to use `inset` with `selector`? when configuring the `android:button` with this `inset` drawable, all my background style was overriden. @martin

Comment: Not working for me. Tried both RadioButton and androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton

Comment: @Martin, You're genius

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Inset drawable causes default animation to break on lower API sometimes.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked gratefully. spent hours for this finally done

Answer (score -2):

Try using paddingStart on the [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html). Since it's extends from a ViewGroup, [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html), all of the child elements will be affected.

```
<RadioGroup
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/radiobuttons"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:dividerPadding="30dp"
   android:paddingStart="8dp">
   <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="How to set the padding on the left of radio pin"
      android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"/>
  <!-- other radio buttons... -->
</RadioGroup>
```

Try this in your background resource.

```
<!-- Background -->
   <item>
      <shape>
         <padding android:left="8dp" />
         <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
         <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
```

Comment: I tried, but all the buttons have moved further to the right and the white border on the left of the pin does not increase...

Comment: Can you add the container_dropshadow.xml . If you're using a 9-patch, then that effect can be easily achievable.

Comment: Ok, edited the question, and added the container_dropshadow.xml

Comment: I hope you're not planning to use the background extensively in your layout. You're going to have some major GPU overdraw. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I tested it and the result is that the pin has the same position and there is a bigger white space beetween the pin and the text...