# Android: Set margin to left side of radiobutton drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-xml

I want to set a margin / padding between my radiobutton drawable and the left side of it, e.g: Setting a margin of 8dp between my radiobutton drawable and the left side of the screen. I know how to set a margin between the radiobutton itself, but not how to do it with the radiobutton drawable. I also know how to set a margin right side of the radiobutton drawable with paddngStart="YOUR_PADDING".

Is this possible?

Here a picture of what I mean:

### Currently

[image]

### What I want

[image]

### EDIT

The aboven written answer does work. For those wo want to set the value inside the layout and not programmatically, I have written a binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("setDrawableLeftPadding")
fun setDrawableLeftPadding(view: CustomRadioButton, padding: Float) {
    view.setStartPaddingDp(padding)
}
```

You can then use it inside your CustomRadioButton layout with `app:setDrawableLeftPadding="@{8f}"`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301636/android-set-padding-to-radiobutton-pin

Comment: @AliAmini I already did, the first answer is useless, and I can't apply the second one because I am getting the drawable via a url and therefore can't set anything inside the `inset`

Comment: Have you tried setting the drawable padding? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671544/6287910

Comment: @Cheticamp Yes I did, writing `android:paddingLeft="20dp" increases the padding between my radiobutton drawable and the text. But I want to increase the padding left side of my radiobutton drawable which does not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to achieve the exact same on what your second picture shows, you can write a custom `RadioButton` that handle this padding, the custom view code can be like this **(in Kotlin)**:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton

class CustomRadioButton : AppCompatRadioButton {

    // the value of your padding (in pixels) from the start of the radio button
    var startPadding: Int = 0
        get
        set(value) {
            field = value
            requestLayout()
        }

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )


    fun setStartPaddingDp(paddingDp: Float) {
        startPaddingPx = (paddingDp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        // todo: handle Right-To-Left layouts
        canvas?.translate(startPadding.toFloat(), 0f)

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth + startPadding, measuredHeight)
    }
}
```

You can set the padding value by setting the value of the field `startPadding`, for example:

```
yourCustomRadioButton.startPadding = 100 // this value is in pixels

// or

yourCustomRadioButton.setStartPaddingDp(100) // this value is in DP
```

Comment: Is it also possible to set the value in dp? Because then this solution would work out for me. And the above code changes the startpadding of my `radiobutton.drawable` and not of the entire radiobutton right?

Comment: Sure you can transform your dp value to px, and set the padding. here is how you can do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62627706/3375081

Comment: Please try the code I posted, so you can make sure if it gives you exactly what your looking for.

Comment: Yes, it does exactly what I want, thank you. But changing the px with dp would help me really much. I would accept it then as the answer

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use the function `setStartPaddingDp` from your customRadioButton.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But you have a typo in there, I think you mean `startPadding = ...` and not `startPaddingPx = ...`

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val compoundButtonDrawable = CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(radioButton)
val insetDrawable = InsetDrawable(compoundButtonDrawable, 32, 0, 0, 0)
radioButton.buttonDrawable = insetDrawable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).